# How to convert currency to decimal

Tags: apex

I am new to Apex and trying to convert Euro to USD and save it in a custom field 'measure'. Here is my code-

```
CurrencyType conversionRate = [SELECT conversionrate from currencytype where isocode = 'Eur'];
 newProduct.measure__c.= opplineItem.Price / (conversionRate);
```

I get the following error

> Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments.

What is the best way to convert conversionRate to decimal. Is there anything like integer.valueof() to convert to decimal?
Thank you

Comment: From what I see in your code, you are trying to divide decimal (opplineItem.Price) by CurrencyType (conversionRate). `CurrencyType` is not decimal and not numeric either.  What you need to do is actually get the conversionrate from CurrencyType variable which is by coincidence also named conversionRate `conversionRate.conversionRate`. It'd be better if you named the CurrencyType variable differently, something like `CurrencyType curType = [SEL...]`, and then access conversionrate like  `curType.conversionrate `. It'd be clearer

Comment: Hi Eduard, it worked! thank you for suggesting to change variable name.

Answer (score 0):

conversionRate (the one with capital R) is a CurrencyType object which is returned by the SOQL.

What you should be doing is :

```
newProduct.measure__c.= opplineItem.Price / (conversionRate.conversionrate);
```

Comment: Hi Chirag, thank you for helping. It works now.